# Unity как сделать объект прозрачным, если в него зашла камера?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Если Камера зашла в объект, то нужно сделать объект прозрачным, как такое реализовать?

Comment: С помощью шейдеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь я помог вам!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "MainCamera") 
        {
            col.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false; // Или true для включение 
            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

На выключение обьекта

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj; // Обьект, который должен изчезнуть

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) // Это триггер 
    {
        if(col.tag == "MainCamera") // Если обьект, который вошел в триггер с тегом "MainCamera" 
        {
            obj.SetActive(false); // То обьект выключается 
        }
    }

}
```

На включение обьекта

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj; // Обьект, который должен включиться

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col) // Это триггер 
    {
        if(col.tag == "MainCamera") // Если обьект, который вошел в триггер с тегом "MainCamera" 
        {
            obj.SetActive(true); // То обьект включется 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Просили на прозрачность объекта, а не на включение-выключение объекта.